# compare two file name from two folder

Tags: php

i have two folder.i always print mp3 folder file name but if image folder have same named file as mp3 file then print both name or no same name then print null.

format like

```
    mp3/
    image/
mp3   image

1   =  1
2   =  2
3   =  null
```

---

i am trying but not success

```
$path = "mp3/";
$ipath = "image/";

if ($handle = opendir($path) && $ihandle = opendir($ipath))
 {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)) && false !==($ifile = readdir($ihandle)))
     {
        if ('.' === $file && $ifile) continue;
        if ('..' === $file && $ifile) continue;
            //var_dump($file);
                    // do something with the file


                            for($i = 1; $i <= count($file); $i++)
                                {

                                $f=current(explode(".", $file));
                                $f1=current(explode(".", $ifile));
                                if($f==$f1)
                                    {

                                    print''.$f.'='.$f1.'';

                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                    print''.$f.'='null';

                                    }
                                }




    }
    closedir($handle);
    closedir($ihandle);
}
```

Comment: This syntax makes no sense: `print''.$f.'='.$f1.'';` I guess it should be: `print $f.'='.$f1;` or better `sprintf('%s=%s', $f, $f1)`. In the current form I'd expect a syntax error to be thrown.

Comment: Also the next one: `print''.$f.'='null';`, this one is not even terminated... It should be: `print $f.'=null'` or `sprintf('%s=null', $f)`.

Comment: if i were you i would read all the file names from one dir and put in array and do the same with another dir then operate on the those two arrays